# How to set file name after merging video files (batch script, FFMPEG)

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, video-editing

I use this bat script for converting .mp4(x264) files to .mp4(x265)

```
for %% in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v hevc "%dp0NewFolder\%%~na[HEVC].mp4"
```

So I'm trying to make another bat script for merging video files(concat).

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do echo file '%%i'>> vlist.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vlist.txt -c copy %~dp0NewFolder\%%~na.mp4
```

Files to merge would be like
Vid_1.mp4,
Vid_2.mp4,
Vid_#.mp4
...

I want to keep the part before "_" in the new file name

What should I use instead of %%~na? To make it just Vid.mp4

Currently it creates %~na.mp4

Answer (score 0):

From what I got you don't need a big scheme to create a output filename since we are talking about 1 filename only, or did I get something wrong?

```
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.mp4') do set "NewVideoName=%%a"& goto :Next
:Next
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vlist.txt -c copy "NewFolder\%NewVideoName%.mp4"
```

Comment: I don't want to name it manually, I was trying to make a batch file, which will do the merging process, and give the new file a name from the files used in merging (like copy name of the first part file but remove anything after _ or - as in vidpart_1, vidpart_2, etc)

Comment: Wow, you took a while to reply....

Comment: Sorry, went through a lot. Opened this site after a long time.

Comment: Try with the edits I made.

Comment: Sorry late again, the code sets file name as
a-d.mp4